# MySQL Error:1064 while calling a stored procedure from an event

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
CREATE EVENT E_UpdateTimestampFields
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE,'00:00:00')
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO `ndwnaleveringen`
CALL spc_UpdateTimeStampFields();
```

This is the code for creating the event which will call a stored procedure spc_UpdateTimeStampFields().  ndwnaleveringen is the name of the database.
While executing this event I am getting the error

> Error Code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL >server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL spc_UpdateTimeStampFields()' at line 7

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CREATE EVENT E_UpdateTimestampFields
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE,'00:00:00')
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO 
  CALL ndwnaleveringen.spc_UpdateTimeStampFields();
```